# Can this algorithm achieve eventual consistency?

Tags: networking, blockchain, eventual-consistency

I have an assumption but I don't know how to prove or falsify it.Please comment if you know:
There are **M** interconnected nodes in a peer-to-peer network. Initially, each node numbers itself with any integer from **1-N, N<=M**.
Each node counts the most occurrences of neighboring nodes, including itself, and modifies its number to that value.
If all the numbers occur equally, a non-self number is randomly selected and changed to that number.
Each node notifies its neighbors when initialization is complete or when the numbering is updated.

Q:
Can this rule achieve final agreement on the numbering of all nodes?
If so, what is the expected time to reach agreement?

Comment: i think this question is better suited for [cs.stackexchange.com](https://cs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I posted an identical question here
https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/146694/can-this-algorithm-achieve-eventual-consistency

Comment: The question is asked already at cs.stackexchange.com, so it should be closed here.